# sql query with foreach loop to add table columns

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting Syntax error for this code... is it possible to have `foreach` loop inside SQL query?

```
try {
    $sql .= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `".$tbl."`(";

    foreach($columns as $column){
        $sql .= "`".$column."` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL,";
}

$sql .= "ID INT( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,";

$DB->exec($sql);
print("Created $tbl Table.\n");

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();//Remove or change message in production code
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: People __can't__ guess error descriptions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first line after try, declare the variable:

```
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `".$tbl."`(";
```

and the error probably it's:

```
$sql .= "ID INT( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,";
```

You need finish the statemant:

```
$sql .= "ID INT( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY )";
```

I hope I have helped.